# LR, W and LM Testing

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, maximum-likelihood

Given the following information on density functions and estimations of the maximum likelihood:

$$\tag{unrestricted}f(y_i\mid x_i,\beta,\rho)=\frac{\beta_i^\rho}{\Gamma(\rho)}y_i^{\rho-1}e^{-y_i\beta_i}$$

$$\tag{$\rho=1$}f(y_i\mid x_i,\beta)=\frac{1}{\beta+x_i}e^{-y_i/(\beta+x_i)}$$

| Quantity | Unrestricted Estimate | Restricted Estimate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\beta$ | -4.7185(2.345) | 15.6027(6.794) |
| $\rho$ | 3.1509(0.794) | 1(0) |
| $\ln L$ | -82.91605 | -88.43626 |
| $\partial\ln L/\partial\beta$ | 0 | 0 |
| $\partial\ln L/\partial\rho$ | 0 | 7.9145 |
| $\partial^2\ln L/\partial\beta^2$ | -0.85570 | -0.02166 |
| $\partial^2\ln L/\partial\rho^2$ | -7.4592 | -32.8987 |
| $\partial^2\ln L/\partial\beta\partial\rho$ | -2.2420 | -0.66891 |

where standard errors are indicated in the brackets, perform

1. the Likelihood ratio test;
2. Wald test;
3. the Lagrange Multiplier test using the expected Hessian to compute the asymptotic covariace matrix. *Hint: the LM-statistic consists of a product of matrices the value of which is 5.1162 hence you are only expected to write out matrices*

and say whether we can reject $H_0$ given that the critical value at $\alpha=0.01$ is $6.635$.

---

So, I assume we don't really need density function to calculate the test statistics since we can you the numbers directly:

1. Using the formula $\text{LR}=2(\ln L_u - \ln L_r)$ we find that LR statistic is $2(-82.91605+88.43626)=11.0404$
2. Using the formula $\text{W}=\frac{(\rho_u-\rho_r)^2)}{\mathbb V[\rho]}$ we find that W statistic is $\frac{(3.1509-1)^2}{0.794^2}=7.3384$
3. Using the formula $\text{LM}=\biggr(\frac{\partial\ln L_r}{\partial\rho}\biggr)\biggr[-\mathbb E[\mathbf H]\biggr]^{-1}\biggr(\frac{\partial\ln L_r}{\partial\rho}\biggr)$ we find that LM statistic is $7.9145\cdot 5.1162^{-1}\cdot7.9145=12.2433$

We see that $\text{LM}>\text{LR}>\text{W}>6.635$ hence $H_0$ can be rejected, i.e. $\rho\neq1$.

Is my approach correct? I'm very not sure since the relationship $\text{W}\ge\text{LR}\ge\text{LM}$ does not hold here. Thanks.